# Nservicebus hello world in process hosting!

Tags: nservicebus

I am trying out nservicebus as a solution instead of using WCF MSMQ binding.
I have tried to get a in process hello world working by mofigying the full duplex sample. I have got it to the point that I am sending message from the client and the server receives it ( guessing by received messages being printed on the server side) but the request message handler is somehow not registered and is not being called on receipt , i.e not hitting breakpoints that I set.

I think i am  supposed to register a handler when configuring the server using -

```
//initialise nservice bus
        Bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
             .Log4Net()
             .DefaultBuilder()
             .XmlSerializer()
             .MsmqTransport()
                 .IsTransactional(false)
                 .PurgeOnStartup(false)
             .UnicastBus()
                 .ImpersonateSender(false)
             .CreateBus()
             .Start();
```

Sorry it could be a very silly question , but just want to get started and the samples are light on in-process hosting examples.

Any pointers or link to examples would be great.

BR
Niladri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing .LoadMessageHandlers() after .UnicastBus().